# Reshaping a numpy array containing images of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array, images, of shape (100,) which contains images of shape (72, 72):

```
images.shape
# returns (100,)

images[0].shape
# returns (72, 72)

images[42].shape
# returns (72, 72)
```

I want to reshape my array to an array of shape = (100, 72, 72), so that the array stores the images "stacked". How do I do this?

Comment: Wait, how is this possible? Doesn't an array of identically shaped arrays automatically become a higher-dimensional array?

Comment: `images.shape` should give `(100, 72, 72)` already, or, why would a `np.array` not be "stacked" already? If images is actually a `list` containing multiple `array`, then you should do `np.array(images)` to make it "stacked".

Comment: @BlownhitherMa If `images` is a list, then `images.shape` is illegal. There is something odd with this question. OP, what does `type(images)` report?

Comment: type(images) reports numpy.ndarray

Comment: images.shape definitely reports (100,)

Comment: Some of your images are _not_ 72x72 (is it why you titled your question "images of different sizes"?). You will not be able to stack them without resizing.

Comment: @DyZ Great idea, but I just checked. They are most certainly all 72x72

Comment: I ran a for loop and manually inspected the sizes of all 100 images

Comment: Did you try `np.stack(images)`?

Comment: Thanks so much hpaulj! That did it. I don't know what was happening.